# Calculating the volume under a surface

Tags: r

I have created a 3D plot (a surface) using `wireframe` function. I wonder if there is any functions by which I can calculate the volume under the surface in a 3D plot?
Here is a sample of my data plus the `wrieframe` syntax I used to create my 3D (surface) plot:

```
x1<-c(13,27,41,55,69,83,97,111,125,139)
x2<-c(27,55,83,111,139,166,194,222,250,278)
x3<-c(41,83,125,166,208,250,292,333,375,417)
x4<-c(55,111,166,222,278,333,389,445,500,556)
x5<-c(69,139,208,278,347,417,487,556,626,695)
x6<-c(83,166,250,333,417,500,584,667,751,834)
x7<-c(97,194,292,389,487,584,681,779,876,974)
x8<-c(111,222,333,445,556,667,779,890,1001,1113)
x9<-c(125,250,375,500,626,751,876,1001,1127,1252)
x10<-c(139,278,417,556,695,834,974,1113,1252,1391)

df<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10)
df.matrix<-as.matrix(df)

wireframe(df.matrix,
      aspect = c(61/87, 0.4),scales=list(arrows=FALSE,cex=.5,tick.number="10",z=list(arrows=T)),ylim=c(1:10),xlab=expression(phi1),ylab="Percentile",zlab=" Loss",main="Random Classifier",
      light.source = c(10,10,10),drape=T,col.regions = rainbow(100, s = 1, v = 1, start = 0, end = max(1,100 - 1)/100, alpha = 1),screen=list(z=-60,x=-60))
```

Note: my real data is a 100X100 matrix

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you are feeding to `wireframe` is a grid of values. Hence one estimate of the volume of whatever underlying surface this is approximating is the sum of the grid values multiplied by the grid cell areas. This is just like adding up the heights of histogram bars to get the number of values in your histogram.

The problem I see with you doing this on your data is that the cell areas are going to be in odd units - percentiles on one axis, `phi` on the other has unknown units, so your volume is going to have units of loss times units of percentile times units of phi.

This isn't a problem if you want to compare volumes of similar things on exactly the same grid, but if you have surfaces on different grids (different values of phi, or different percentiles) then you need to be careful.

Now, noting that `wireframe` doesn't draw like a 3d histogram would (looking like square tower blocks) this gives us another way to estimate the volume. Your 10x10 matrix is plotted as 9x9 squares. Divide each of those squares into triangles and then compute the volume of the 192 right truncated triangular prisms (I think this is what they are - they are equilateral triangular prisms with a right angle and one sloping end). The formula for that should be out there somewhere. Probably base area times height to the centroid of the triangle or something.

I thought maybe this would be in the raster package, but it isn't. There's code for computing the surface area but not the volume! I'm sure the raster maintainer would be happy to have some code for this!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I just added a sample of my data to the above question. I would be thankful if you had a look at it.

Comment: Thank you Spaceman for your comprehensive answer! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If the points are arbitrary (ie, don't follow smooth function), it seems like you're looking for the volume of the convex hull (minimum surface) surrounding these points. One package to help you calculate this is  [alphashape3d](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/alphashape3d/alphashape3d.pdf).

You'll need a 3-column matrix of the coordinates to form the right type of object to make the calculation but it seems rather straight-forward.