# How to calculate the volume under a surface defined by discrete data?

Tags: r, interpolation, spline, numerical-integration

I need to determine the volume beneath a series of surfaces represented by discrete data points. In my data, each sample is stored as a separate data frame within a list of data frames. Here is some (small) example data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=c(2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6),
                  y=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                  z=c(0,2,0,4,6,7,3,2,1,2,7,8,9,4,2))

df2 <- data.frame(x=c(2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6),
                  y=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                  z=c(1,1,2,3,5,6,2,1,3,3,8,9,8,3,1))

DF <- list(df1,df2)
```

Answers to similar questions are either in other languages (matlab, python), or the answers do not contain useable script to address the problem ([as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381903/calculating-the-volume-under-a-surface)). I can think of two acceptable ways to estimate the volume beneath each surface: 1) write out a discretized version of simpson's rule as a function in R that is applied across the list of data frames (DF); 2) calculate an arbitrary relationship between x, y, and z and use multivariate numerical integration to find the volume under the surface (with functions like simpson2d / quad2d in the package pracma or adaptIntegrate in cubature).

Regarding the first approach, the formula for the composite simpson's rule (that I would like to use) is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmVu3.jpg), but due to its complexity, I have been unsuccessful in writing a working double summation function. In this expression, I(lambda(em) lambda(ex)) is equal to z in the above datasets at each x,y grid point, and Delta(em) and Delta(ex) represent the interval between x and y points.

The second approach would essentially extend the approach [found here](https://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/software/r-advanced-statistical-package/numerical-integrationdifferentiation-r-ftir-spectra/) to multivariate spline fits and then pass the predicted z values as a function for integration. Here's what I have tried so far for this approach:

```
require(pracma)

df1.loess <- loess(z ~ x + y, data=DF[[1]])
mod.fun <- function(x,y) predict(df1.loess, newdata=x,y)

simpson2d(mod.fun, x=c(2,6), y=c(1,3))
```

But this does not yield useful results.

In reality, I have a list of almost 100 data frames for individual samples, so I really need to be able to express the solution as a series of lapply functions that automate these calculations across all data frames in the list. An example looks something like this:

```
require(akima)
DF.splines <- lapply(DF, function(x,y,z) interp(x = "x", y = "y", z = "z",
                                                linear=F, nx=4, ny=2))
```

Unfortunately, this produces an exception for missing values and Infs. I'm extremely open to any suggestions for how to successfully implement one of these strategies, or to utilize a different (simpler?) approach. Could a kriging function (like km in the DiceKriging package) produce a better fit that could be passed on for numerical integration?

Comment: Are your shapes convex?

Comment: Yes, each data frame describes a rectangular region with even intervals between x and y coordinates. I'm looking for the area beneath the randomly fluctuating surface of z values. These regions should be convex.

Comment: Oh, I did not see that the x,y grid is regular. Convex means that for any two points that you take from within your volume, all points on the straight line connecting that two points are within the volume. So if the z values are arbitrary, the volumes are most likely not convex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the volume surface mesh is defined by connecting points via straight lines. Then you can find the volume beneath that surface via

1. triangular tessellation of the `(x,y)` grid into triangles `T_i` with area `A_i`
2. finding the corresponding `z` values `Z_i` for each of the triangles `T_i`
3. calculating the volume `V_i` of the truncated prisms (defined by `T_i` and `Z_i`) via `V_i=A_i*sum(Z_i)/3` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_(geometry) and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371139/volume-of-truncated-prism)
4. summing up all truncated prism volumes `V_i`

Keep in mind, however, that the volume does depend on your tessellation and that the tessellation is not unique. But your problem is not fully defined in the sense that it does not describe how one should interpolate between points. So any approach to calculate a volume will have to make additional assumptions.

Going back to my solution approach, points 1 and 2 can be achieved via the `geometry` package.
Here some code

```
library(geometry)

getVolume=function(df) {
  #find triangular tesselation of (x,y) grid
  res=delaunayn(as.matrix(df[,-3]),full=TRUE,options="Qz")
  #calulates sum of truncated prism volumes
  sum(mapply(function(triPoints,A) A/3*sum(df[triPoints,"z"]),
             split.data.frame(res$tri,seq_along(res$areas)),
             res$areas))
}

sapply(DF,getVolume)
#[1] 32.50000 30.33333
```

Since it's hard to check whether the results are consistent, here a simple example where we know the right answer. It's a cube with side length 2 where we have cut out a wedge along the x axis. The cut-out region is 1/4 of the total volume.

```
cutOutCube=expand.grid(c(0,1,2),c(0,1,2))
colnames(cutOutCube)=c("x","y")
cutOutCube$z=ifelse(cutOutCube$x==1,1,2)

sapply(list(cutOutCube),getVolume)
#[1] 6
```

That's correct since `2^3*(1-1/4)=6`.

Another sanity check can be performed by calculating the "complement" of the volume w.r.t. to a simple cuboid where all `z` values are set to the max `z` value (in your case `max(z)=9` in both cases). The simple cuboid volumes are 72 for both of your cases. Not let's define the complement surfaces and sum up volume and complement volume

```
df1c=df1
df1c$z=max(df1c$z)-df1c$z
df2c=df2
df2c$z=max(df2c$z)-df2c$z
DFc=list(df1c,df2c)

sapply(DFc,getVolume)+sapply(DF,getVolume)
#[1] 72 72
```

So volume and complement volume give the right simple cuboid volume in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could approximate the surface through a "barycentric Lagrangian" approach as implemented in function `barylag2d` in the *pracma* package. Then, to avoid any vectorization problems, apply the Gaussian quadrature rules explicitly.

```
library(pracma)

df1 <- data.frame(x=c(2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6),
                  y=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                  z=c(0,2,0,4,6,7,3,2,1,2,7,8,9,4,2))

# Define the nodes in x- and y-direction
xn <- df1$x[c(1,4,7,10,13)]
yn <- df1$y[1:3]

# Define the matrix representing the function
m1 <- matrix(df1$z, nrow=5, byrow=TRUE)
f <- function(x, y) 
        c(pracma::barylag2d(m1, xn, yn, x, y))

# 32 nodes in integration intervals
n <- 32
xa <- 2; xb <- 6; ya <- 1; yb <- 3

# Apply quadrature rules explicitely
cx <- gaussLegendre(n, xa, xb)
x <- cx$x; wx <- cx$w
cy <- gaussLegendre(n, ya, yb)
y <- cy$x; wy <- cy$w

# Sum weights * values over all nodes
I <- 0
for (i in 1:n) {
  for (j in 1:n) {
    I <- I + wx[i] * wy[j] * f(x[i], y[j])
  }
}
I  # 40.37037
```

The integral value of 40 seems reasonable given the data. `simpson2d` or `quad2d` will not work in this setting.

You may try whether `adaptIntegrate` will work with the so defined function `f`.